# Eject disk on Mac Pro running VMWare ESXi

Tags: mac, vmware-esxi, optical-media

I'm almost embarrassed to ask this, but I'm stuck.  I installed VMWare ESXi on a Mac Pro.  It's working great!   The problem is that you press F12 to eject the disk, and F12 is what you use to shutdown ESX.  I can power down, open the case, pull out the CD drive and use a paper clip to force the drawer open, but that's kind of a pain.

Any other way to do this?

EDIT: Setting password was a good idea - no shutdown now :)  However, F12 doesn't eject the disk when VMWare is running.  Attaching the drive to a VM and ejecting from there ("Eject" in Windows Explorer for example) does work.  Kind of a round about way though.  But maybe that's the best I can do with this Mac.  Wish they had exposed the eject button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried binding the physical drive to one of the VMs and then issuing an eject command?

Comment: This seems to be the only way to get the disk out while the machine is running (ie without a reboot).  Not sure why, but F12 wouldn't do it from within VMWare.

Answer (score 4):

Holding the mouse button down while rebooting the machine will eject the disk.

Comment: I *think* he's looking to do this with the server running, could be wrong though.

Answer (score 4):

Try issuing the **eject** command on the ESXi service console via SSH

http://vmwaretips.com/wp/2008/10/20/access-the-esxi-service-console/

Answer (score 3):

Set a password - that way F12 WON'T shut down you box without you entering it first.

Comment: Spot on as far as ESXi is concerned but will F12 still eject the drive when the Mac Pro isn't running OSX?

Comment: Yeah, it's an EFI-thang, works the same in windows before you install the bootcamp code.